# Valgrind says about "Invalid write" in fclose()

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind

I created a stream using fmemopen(). I am closing it with fclose() and freeing the buffer after reading. Valgrind reports about problem at fclose() line:

```
==9323== Invalid write of size 8
==9323==    at 0x52CAE52: _IO_mem_finish (memstream.c:139)
==9323==    by 0x52C6A3E: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:63)
==9323==    by 0x400CB6: main (main.cpp:80)
==9323==  Address 0xffefffa80 is just below the stack ptr.  To suppress, 
use: --workaround-gcc296-bugs=yes
```

What's happening? Maybe fclose() cannot properly close a memory stream? Or maybe valgrind worries without reason and I can ignore that?

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: You should be able to reproduce the problem with a small [tag:C] program (that will make it easier to track down, rather than calling from [tag:C++]).

Comment: @TobySpeight: there's nothing wrong with c++. don't complicate his life.

Comment: We need a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Karoly - I'm actually trying to simplify the question.  A minimal C++ example is probably identical to the minimal C example; in which case tagging the question as C might get more viewers.  Until we get a [minimal complete verifiable example](/help/mcve) it's a moot point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. I wrote that I use fmemopen() to open a stream, but this code wasn't running, and I get stream, produced earlier with open_memstream(). Although this stream was opened for writing, I can read from it. However valgrind reports about problem. I fixed my code, valgrind find no errors.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted your code, the following is pure speculation.  You're probably writing more output to the stream than you promised to when you opened it.  Did you account for the final NUL (if you didn't open with `"b"`)?

Did you read the following in the manual page?

> When  a stream that has been opened for writing is flushed (`fflush`(3)) or closed (`fclose`(3)), a null byte is written at the end of the buffer if there is space.  The caller should ensure that an extra byte is available in
>          the buffer (and that `size` counts that byte) to allow for this.
>
> Attempts to write more than `size` bytes to the buffer result in an error.  (By default, such errors will be visible only when the stdio buffer is flushed.  Disabling buffering with `setbuf(fp, NULL)` may be useful to  detect
>          errors at the time of an output operation.  Alternatively, the caller can explicitly set buf as the stdio stream buffer, at the same time informing stdio of the buffer's size, using `setbuffer(fp, buf, size)`.)

Following the latter advice should reveal the write that is exceeding the capacity.